# Why do I have to use an aggregate function on this column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
+---------+---------------+------------+-------+
| country | company       | date       | sales |
+---------+---------------+------------+-------+
| US      | Amazon        | 2019-11-01 | 100   |  
| US      | Amazon        | 2019-12-01 | 120   |   
| US      | Apple         | 2019-11-01 | 100   | 
| US      | Apple         | 2019-12-01 | 150   | 
| DE      | Amazon        | 2019-11-01 | 200   | 
| DE      | Amazon        | 2019-12-01 | 300   |
+---------+---------------+------+-----+-------+
```

I want to calculate the monthly growth rate of the sales in percentage for each of the companies, for each country. This is my SQL code:

```
select date_trunc('month', date),
        country,
        sum(sales),
        round(1.0 - sales::numeric/nullif(lag(sales::numeric, 1) over (order by date),0) *100,1) prev
from table 
group by date, country
order by date asc;
```

When I run the code, this error appears:

> column "table.sales" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `sum(sales)` instead of `sales` when aggregating, also `partition by country` in `over` and `group by date_trunc('month', date)`:

```
select date_trunc('month', date),
        country,
        sum(sales),
        round(sum(sales)::numeric/nullif(lag(sum(sales)::numeric, 1) over (partition by country order by date_trunc('month', date)),0) *100 - 100,1) prev
from tablename 
group by date_trunc('month', date), country
order by date_trunc('month', date) asc;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hmLQ3acoeqJMNJChH9a6Q/4).

Comment: Why do you want output for Amazon? Don't you want to group by country?

Comment: I think the number after `round(` should be 200, because the growth (in the link DE) shows as -50, when it's actually +50. Same thing with other results

Comment: I kept the logic of your cod in my code but maybe you want this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hmLQ3acoeqJMNJChH9a6Q/4

Comment: I edited, and maybe you should rename the column to something like `monthly_growth` rather than `prev`

Answer (score 2):

Because you need to lag the SUM of the sales, not the column itself:

```
select date_trunc('month', date), country, sum(sales),
       round(1.0 - sum(sales)::numeric * 100.0 /
             nullif(lag(sum(sales)::numeric, 1) 
       over (order by date), 0), 1) prev
from table 
group by date, country
order by date asc;
```

Comment: @Snow change both `sales::numeric` to `sum(sales)::numeric`.

Comment: @forpas thanks, that removed the error. However, the new column's results don't seem to be correct